# Nested query on ElasticSearch for Long type (ES 5.0.4)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

This is my first question on Stack overflow , please excuse me for the mistakes. I will improve on them in the future.
I am new to Elastic Search too. Okay so I am trying to do a exact match in elastic search (5.0.4). Instead of doing an exact match, the request returns all the documents present.
Not sure of this behavior.

Here is the mapping

```
{
   "properties":{
      "debug_urls":{
         "properties":{
            "characteristics":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "url_id":{
               "type":"long"
            }
         },
         "type":"nested"
      },
      "scanId":{
         "type":"text",
         "fields":{
            "keyword":{
               "type":"keyword",
               "ignore_above":256
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my request.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "debug_urls",
           "query": {
               "match": {
                  "debug_urls.url_id": 1
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The response received,

```
{
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":1,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"cust_cca39c0c6c8141008e9411032bbf4d21",
            "_type":"debug-urls",
            "_id":"AW70h0l72s9qXitMsWgC",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{
               "scan_id":"n_a0a523fb5c81435fb79c34c624c7fbd6",
               "debug_urls":[
                  {
                     "url_id":1,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "FORM",
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":2,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":3,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":4,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":5,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":6,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "url_id":7,
                     "characteristics":[
                        "EXTERNAL_SCRIPT",
                        "INLINE_SCRIPT"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to see the matching nested documents?

Comment: Yes. In my care I want an exact match on the field url_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to see the nested documents that match the criteria, you can leverage [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits):

```
{
    "_source":["scan_id"],                     <--- add this line
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "debug_urls",
           "query": {
               "match": {
                  "debug_urls.url_id": 1
               }
           },
           "inner_hits": {}                    <--- add this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this not working..I will add the output I see for reference in the question.

Comment: Did you add the output?

Comment: yup had added in the question under  - The response received, ..and thanks for the replies!

Comment: See my updated answer, please try again. The hits you're looking for are below the `_source` in the `inner_hits` section

Comment: worked! thanks a ton! If its not much of an effort can you elaborate on the lines you have added or point me to some links / docs with more info on them..